# Difference between Aspects, concerns and cross-cutting concerns in Spring AOP

Tags: aop, aspect, cross-cutting-concerns

Can anyone please explain the difference between Aspects, concerns and cross-cutting concerns in Spring AOP with example? I have gone through a lot of tutorial sites but I didn't get any good explanation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking terminology questions which can be looked up in manuals or even Wikipedia (see the links in my answer). There is no technical question with sample code which could be analysed or answered/solved correctly.

Answer (score -4):

Actually, your question is not well-suited for StackOverflow because you are asking for terminology definitions rather than about a concrete programming problem with sample code. Anyway, if it helps, please read these articles about AOP and related terminology:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern

Comment: I think if the person asks terminology question in SO, he already read about it in Wikipedia.

Comment: I doubt that, because that very termiology is explained both in the encyclopedia articles I linked to and probably also in the tutorials the OP claims to have read, most prominently in the Spring manual right at the beginning of the AOP section, e.g. in the very first paragraph of [5. Aspect Oriented Programming with Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop) and in [5.1. AOP Concepts](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-introduction-defn).

Comment: Furthermore, SO is about programming, not about terminology questions, like I explained in my answer. Actually, the question should be deleted or closed as off-topic. I was just being nice, giving a quick hint (instead of reciting or repeating other sources) because the OP was a new user at the time of asking his question. I think I deserve better than your downvote for that.